# move the second div to first position using css

Tags: css, css-grid

i have one parent div , inside the parent div i have 3 children divs.

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">First</div>
        <div class="child2">Second</div>
        <div class="child3">Third</div>
</div>
```

For parent i already write below style.

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Expectation is

```
Second  First Third
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property:

For example by putting `order: -1` the item will be placed at the begining
Working example below

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child2 {
  order: -1 /*Moves it to the first place*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">First</div>
  <div class="child2">Second</div>
  <div class="child3">Third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `order` parameter on the children:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child1 {
  order: 2;
}

.child2 {
  order: 1;
}

.child3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">First</div>
  <div class="child2">Second</div>
  <div class="child3">Third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `order` CSS property, you can also use the `grid-template-areas` property on the parent and `grid-area` property on the children if you prefer to use a label for the ordering rather than a number.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "col-1 col-2 col-3";
}

.child1 { grid-area: col-2; }
.child2 { grid-area: col-1; }
.child3 { grid-area: col-3; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">First</div>
  <div class="child2">Second</div>
  <div class="child3">Third</div>
</div>
```